# How to find a most reliable basis In a binary matrix?

Tags: matlab, matrix

I want to write a MATLAB program that allows to do the following instructions, however i am having some difficulties, so i would be very thankful if someone help me.

Let a binary matrix A. Starting from the first column of A, find the first K linearly independent columns with the largest associated reliability values. Then, these K linearly independent columns are used as the first K columns of a new matrix B, maintaining their reliability order. The remaining (N − K) columns of B are also arranged in decreasing reliability order.

Example :

```
A = [1 0 0 1 0 0 1 1;
     0 1 0 1 1 0 0 1;
     0 0 1 1 1 0 1 0;
     0 0 0 0 1 1 1 1]
```

The first three columns of A are linearly independent, the fifth column is linearly independent of the first three columns.

we find :

```
B = [1 0 0 0 1 0 1 1;
     0 1 0 1 1 0 0 1;
     0 0 1 1 1 0 1 0;
     0 0 0 1 0 1 1 1]
```

Comment: What do you mean with "_largest associated reliability values_"?

Comment: The columns of the matrix A are classified according to their reliability values, ie the first column is more reliable than the second column, the second column is more reliable than the third column and so on.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`rank`](https://mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/rank.html) to determine if the columns are linearly independent as follows:

```
K = size(A, 1); % the number of linearly independent columns to find
B = zeros(size(A)); % preallocate output for efficiency
colB = 1; % column index for the next linearly independent column
colBafter = K + 1; % column index for the next linearly dependent column

for i=1:size(A, 2) % loop over all columns in A
  B(:, colB) = A(:, i); % add the next column of A as an independent column to B
  if rank(B(:, 1:colB)) == colB % check if the newly added column is indeed linearly independent
    if colB == K % check if all independent columns are found
      break;
    else
      colB = colB + 1; % increase the independent index as the added column was indeed linearly independent
    end
  else
    B(:, colBafter) = A(:, i); % add the column as a dependent column to B
    colBafter = colBafter + 1; % increase the dependent index as the added column was linearly dependent
  end
end

B(:, colBafter:end) = A(:, i+1:end); % copy the rest of A to B
```

Comment: Thanks @m7913d ! That's exactly what i was searching for.